# Homework Help - Summation with Three Variables

Tags: analysis, sequences-and-series

I am currently studying for an Algorithms class. In my notes from class and in the my textbook, there is not a similar example I can reference. I have worked on the problem and gone to tutoring, but I can not seem to get the correct answer.

Can anyone give me any tips on how to solve this problem?

> Evaluate the summation, where $a$ is a constant, $a \neq 1$.
>
> a) $\displaystyle\sum_{i={10}}^n (a^i+n)$, where $a\neq 1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There aren't three variables in the sumation, there is only one ($n$); $a$ is a fixed quantity, so it does not *vary*, and $i$ is the index of the summation.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the sum into a sum of powers of $a$, and a sum of $n$. The latter is trivial.

For the former, you are obviously expected to use the [formula for the sum of a geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score 0):

By three variables do you mean a,n, and i?

You will have to choose one value for a and n.
i will go from 10 to n.

For example if a = 3 and n=20 your pseudocode would be:

int a =3;
   int n = 20
   answer = 0;
   for(i=10:i==n;i++){answer += a^i+ n}

There are more elegant ways, but this is a tiny assignement. Arturo is right that you could use the formula for a geometric series too.